# Adding an associative array to another associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two separate arrays.

**Array 1:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Product 1
            [quantity] => 2
            [unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => GBP
                    [value] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Product 2
            [quantity] => 4
            [unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => GBP
                    [value] => 
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Product 3
            [quantity] => 6
            [unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => GBP
                    [value] => 
                )

        )

)
```

and **Array 2:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
)
```

I don't know how to make `[value]` in each array from **Array 1** receive consecutive values from **Array 2**. What I need is this:

**Array 1**:

```
[unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => GBP
                    [value] => 3
                )
[unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => GBP
                    [value] => 4
                )
[unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => GBP
                    [value] => 5
                )
```

This is how **Array 1** is created. It's contained in `$products_details[]`:

```
<?php
foreach ($basket as $product) {
    $product_detail['id'] = $product['product_id'];
    $product_detail['name'] = $product['product_name'];
    $product_detail['quantity'] = $product['product_quantity'];
    $product_detail['unit_amount']['currency_code'] = $currency_code;
    $product_detail['unit_amount']['value'] = '';

    $products_details[] = $product_detail;
?>
```

This is how **Array 2** is created:

```
<?php
foreach ($basket_prices as $price) {
    $product_detail_more[] = $price;
}
$products_details_more[] = $product_detail_more;
?>
```

**The combination of both arrays should be contained in `$items[]`.**

Here is an example of what I have tried:

```
<?php
foreach ($products_details as $arr) {
    $arr['unit_amount']['value'] = $price;
    $items[] = $arr;
}
?>
```

but it adds only the last value from **Array 2**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Product 1
            [quantity] => 2
            [unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => GBP
                    [value] => 5 // The last value from Array 2 received.
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Product 2
            [quantity] => 4
            [unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => GBP
                    [value] => 5 // The last value from Array 2 received.
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Product 3
            [quantity] => 6
            [unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => GBP
                    [value] => 5 // The last value from Array 2 received.
                )

        )

)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the arrays are all available. And I am assuming that `Array 2:` is the `$basket_prices` array

```
foreach ($basket as $i => $product) {
// add an index     ^^
    $product_detail['id'] = $product['product_id'];
    $product_detail['name'] = $product['product_name'];
    $product_detail['quantity'] = $product['product_quantity'];
    $product_detail['unit_amount']['currency_code'] = $currency_code;
    $product_detail['unit_amount']['value'] = $basket_prices[$i];
// use the index to address the other array   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    $products_details[] = $product_detail;
```

Comment: Yes,  `Array 2` is `$basket_prices` and all the arrays are available. I've tried your code. It gives me two errors: `Undefined offset: 3`, `Undefined offset: 4` which seems to be related with `$basket_prices[$i]`.

Comment: Well that means your `basket` array is bigger than your `basket_prices` array! What would you do about that in real life

Comment: Actually, the array `basket` contains those values too. (I was passing the same values via two different routes for certain reason.) So, instead of `$basket_prices[$i]` I put `$product['product_price'][$i]` and it works now. I don't need the other array. I think I was making the problem more complex than it really was. Many thanks for your help.